# Add labels on JSON respond

Tags: json

first post here.
I have a raspberry with openenergymonitor running.
I can get data using JSON for some values.

Example:
http://192.168.1.252/feed/fetch.json?ids=4,5

Respond:
[24.43,41.76]

Is there a way to manipulate the url so to change the respond to:
[Temperature: 24.43, Humidity: 41.76]

Best regards.

Comment: What language do you use? and pls post the code you used to get the response.

Comment: Hey thank for your respond. 
Not sure what the server uses. 

I have installed open energy monitor in one raspberry. 
https://blog.openenergymonitor.org/2012/05/installing-emoncms-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: The server stores my energy consumption and temperature of my house. 

I can access the feeds like the url I have posted on my first post. 

The question is if there is a generic way to change the output of the respond as I described on the first post. By changing the url I enter.